# Why code in finally will execute even it has returned in try block?

Tags: java, try-catch, finally

Code:

```
public String get() {
try {
     //doSomething
     return "Hello";
}
finally {
     System.out.print("Finally");
}
```

How does this code execute?

Comment: Did you try it? It's very easy to verify.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because that's the whole point of a `finally` block - it executes however you leave the `try` block, unless the VM itself is shut down abruptly.

Typically `finally` blocks are used to clean up resources - you wouldn't want to leave a file handle open just because you returned during the `try` block, would you? Now you *could* put that clean-up code just before the return statement - but then it wouldn't be cleaned up if the code threw an exception instead. With `finally`, the clean-up code executes *however* you leave the block, which is generally what you want.

See [JLS section 14.20.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html#14.20.2) for more details - and note how all paths involve the `finally` block executing.

Answer (score 3):

Finally ***ALWAYS*** gets executed, no matter what happens in the try block (fail, return, exception, finish etc.).

If you don't want this code to be executed, you could always placed it after the try/catch/finally statement.

Comment: Except if the JVM doesn't live to run it ;-) I.e. if the JVM gets killed or the computer loses power.

Comment: Agreed... but then NO code is going to get run, which I feel is kind of obvious... ;)

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what `finally` is for: the code inside *will* execute when the `try` block is left, no matter how (except the JVM shutting down via `System.exit()` or external reasons).